# `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, crud

This is what my *serializers.py* file is looking like:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import *

class EinsatzSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta: 
        model = Einsatz
        fields = ('pk', 'url', ...)  # ... = all my other fields
```

But when I create an "Einsatz", I get this error:

```
Exception Value:    `HyperlinkedIdentityField` requires the request in the serializer context. Add `context={'request': request}` when instantiating the serializer.

Exception Location:     .../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py, line 378, in to_representation
```

I don't understand why I am getting this Error, when I am not even using `HyperlinkedIdentityField`. And where would I even put `context={'request': request}`?

I also have a *views.py* and *urls.py* to show if needed.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have a field called 'url'? I think you should change the name..